# Is it good practice for void methods to return?

Tags: refactoring, anti-patterns

The return statement is being used in void methods to break out of the logic here. The problem is the consumers of the method wouldn’t know whether the logic in the method ran completely or not, when we do this. However my architect and teams don't agree with that. The reason is that the current consumer in this case doesn't care about the outcome.

I think this is coding anti-pattern. It is like eating exception with out bubbling it up. What's everyone's opinion on this?

Existing code:

```
Private void XXX(final String parameter) {
        try {
            if (parameter==null){
                return;
            }
            ....
    }
```

My version

```
Private boolean XXX(final String parameter) {
        try {
            if (parameter==null){
                return false;
            }
            ....
    return true;
    }
```

Comment: Encapsulation is all about the costumer not knowing exactly which logic ran. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

In general having multiple `return`s is not necessarily an anti-pattern.  At worst there might be many exit points in the method which can be confusing for developers who are reading the code and perhaps make it harder to maintain...maybe but that is not what you seem to be asking.

The code samples you provided appear to me to both be anti-patterns.

> The problem is the consumers of the method wouldn’t know whether the logic in the method ran completely or not, when we do this.

First, that is what `Exception`s are for.  If there is a problem while executing the code in the method, throw an Exception with an intent revealing type and a good message describing the problem.

The first version of your code:

```
Private void XXX(final String parameter) {
    try {
        if (parameter==null){
            return;
        }
        ....
}
```

seemed to return instead of throwing an Exception with an invalid argument.

The second version of the code:

```
Private boolean XXX(final String parameter) {
    try {
        if (parameter==null){
            return false;
        }
        ....
return true;
}
```

Seems to return a `boolean` as an exit code of "worked" or "didn't work".  This isn't very helpful because if it didn't work, you don't know why.  Also it requires the calling code to check the return value which they might forget to do.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with having an explicit return for a void method. However, it is good general practice--if possible--to have just one return from a method (although you can have more than one if logic demands it and you write the code as simply as possible--no blocks--so that the overall flow is not obfuscated).

Should you simply return in the case you cite? It all depends on the requirements. Your customers appear to be the programmers who will call this method. Do they consider a null parameter to be a logic error for the method or do they consider it to be valid?

If it's the former then I suggest you use an annotation (@NotNull) to ensure that parameter is not null. Unfortunately, there are several of these to choose from so you will have to figure out which suits your architecture best.

If you really don't want to use an annotation (and null is considered an error) then throw an exception.